# PWA with firebase / iOS and Android click issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

i have a running PWA where the notifications work pretty well, also for iOS and Android. The only problem i have is when clicking on the notification:

1. On Android: its just closing, no opening of the PWA
2. On iOS: it opens PWA but does not open the click_action URL i am passing

---

Here is the code of the service worker:

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.1/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js");

firebase.initializeApp({
    xxx
});

let isStandalone = false;
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(({ notification, data }) => {
    if (isStandalone) {
        const notificationTitle = notification.title;
        const notificationOptions = {
            body: notification.body,
        };

        if (data.click_action) {
            notificationOptions.data = {};
            notificationOptions.data.click_action = data.click_action;
        }

        self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
    }
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var notification = event.notification;
    var action = event.action;

    if (action === 'close') {
        notification.close();
    } else {
        if (notification.data.click_action) {
            event.waitUntil(
                clients.openWindow(notification.data.click_action + '?initReload=true').then(function(windowClient) {
                }).catch(function(error) { })
            );
        }
        notification.close();
    }
});

self.addEventListener('message', event => {
    if (event.data && event.data.type === 'DISPLAY_MODE') {
        isStandalone = event.data.mode === 'standalone';
    }
});
```

Here is part of init the service worker:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js').then(function(registration) {
                navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
                    if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                        navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({
                            type: 'DISPLAY_MODE',
                            mode: 'standalone'
                        });
                    }
                });
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Service worker registration failed:', error);
            });
        }
```

Does anybody had same issue and where able to solve it?